# Rate of reaction

Tags: kinetics

For a reaction say
$$\ce{nA->B}$$ with $$\text{rate} =k[A]^n$$
So do we write rate as $ \frac {-\mathrm d[A]}{\mathrm dt}$  or $\frac{1}{n} \frac {-\mathrm d[A]}{\mathrm dt}$ We have only been taught for $n = 1$, and I couldn't thin which one should be correct. It will be really helpful if you can also include the reason why.

Comment: $1/n$ https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/R/R05156.html

Comment: $$\text{Rate of disappearance}~A= \frac {-\mathrm d[A]}{\mathrm dt}$$
$$\text{Standard rate} =\frac{1}{n} \frac {-\mathrm d[A]}{\mathrm dt}=\frac {\mathrm d[B]}{\mathrm dt}$$
The vlaue of $k$ depends on how you define the rate.